# Use Webpack library and libraryTarget configuration to set our custom library via global var

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I have a library "xyz" which is currently being imported as a node module through npm registry.

Now, I want to add it as a library and expose it via global name "abc".

I want to use [webpack configuration](https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html) to achieve that.

So, I understand that this is the config i need to add to my webpack config?:

```
 "output": {
        "path": SHELL_PATH + filePath.dist,
        "libraryTarget": "var",
        "library": "abc"
    }
```

But, then how do i link abc to my xyz library so that the methods inside my abc library are exposed through global name "abc"?

What else do i need to do?

Comment: Do you mean wrapping `xyz` library inside `abc`? Or modifying `xyz` library to be exposed as a global `abc` variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option could be just wrapping `xyz` inside `abc` library and expose `abc` library as a global variable.

### webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    libraryTarget: 'var',
    library: 'abc',
    path: './dist',
    filename: 'abc.js'
  }
};
```

### index.js

```
module.exports = {
  xyz: require('xyz')
};
```

if you want to access `xyz` fields through `abc.xyz`, or

```
module.exports = require('xyz');
```

if you want to export `xyz` fields through `abc` directly.