# Webpack - Trimming Build Time - multiple versions

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, build, npm, webpack

My webpack build takes in excess of 13sec to build. So I started reviewing the dependencies. Here is one I found for lodash by running the command `npm ls lodash`:

[image: multiple version of lodash in webpack build]

Is my understanding correct that there are three versions of lodash installed within this repo & being loaded simultaneously (@1.0.2, @4.16.3, @4.16.4)?

Comment: If you use NPM v3 or yarn your dependencies are already as flat and simplified as possible without breaking their compatibility as specified in package.json. There is no safe/easy way to flatten your dependency tree even more or speed up builds.

Comment: Best way I've found in speeding up builds is to use DLL's..  Recently though I've been looking at jspm.io, this has a nice option were as you develop it leaves things unpacked, it's only when you need to pack for redistribution do you have to do the build.  I've only just started looking though, so not sure if it can do everything webpack can.

Comment: @Ambroos that totally went over my head, plainer english please. :)

Comment: @Keith yes, read about DLL & going to look into it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Webpack library and libraryTarget configuration to set our custom library via global var](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33510712/use-webpack-library-and-librarytarget-configuration-to-set-our-custom-library-vi)